# How can we make a extension live in typo3?

Tags: extension-methods, typo3, typo3-tca

I created a extension  in typo3 and would like to make it live .Can any one explain the step to be follow?

Comment: Please define "make it live". Did you create a plugin and want to insert it on a frontend page, did you create a backend module you want to make accessible, do you want to publish your extension to the TYPO3 extension repository, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create an account in typo3.org.
2. Then in the typo3 backend (of your website)"Extension Manager > Settings" tab - enter your typo3.org account login credentials and save it.
3. "Extension Manager > Available extensions" tab - click on your extension and then use the "TER upload" option.

Have a nice day :) !

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit general. In order to create your own extension in Typo3, you first need to install an extension called "`Extbase`" in your `Typo3 Extension Manager` which can help you fasten your development.

Then, you can start your development right a way. After finish, simply install it and use it as plugin(s) to your Typo3 site.

Go to this link for more information: http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development

Comment: Ok thank you.But i completed created an extension using kick-starter and i would like to make that extension live, which can access by all users.