# TYPO3: Uploading my extension in the TER

Tags: typo3

I'm not sure if this question belongs in StackOverflow, but I didn't know where else to post it.

I have built a TYPO3 extension, and I think it could be useful to other people, so I was wondering what is the protocol to upload it to the TYPO3 Extension Repository (TER). I haven't been able to find any kind of documentation.

Someone in IRC said that "he thought" I had to sign some sort of agreement, but since he wasn't sure, and I find it quite bizarre, I wanted to see if someone else could offer me a more solid answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476877/how-can-we-make-a-extension-live-in-typo3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First signup on the TYPO3 site,

Then go to http://typo3.org/extensions/extension-keys/ and register new unique key for your ext

Then from your backend - ExtensionMenager login with your credentials and upload it

Comment: I see. It was grayed out because I wasn't logged in. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: It seems what in TYPO3 6.1 it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Extension Uploader" extension http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_uploader

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many ways how you can do it. The most basic way is like biesior (and Fedir) described it. Upload it manually on typo3.org.

If you want to upload it directly from your git repo, you can use github and a service that upload all tagged versions automatically to the TER.

Its brilliant described here: http://typo3worx.eu/2016/07/5-ways-to-publish-a-typo3-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Since December 2020 the new REST API for TYPO3 Extension repository is available.
It is now easier to to upload extensions to TER. You don't have to use login and password, but can generate the access token and use it to publish the extension.

There is also an official tool which helps you communicate with the TER API:
https://github.com/TYPO3/tailor

You can read more about the new API and other improvements here:
https://typo3.org/article/a-new-way-to-manage-your-extensions-in-the-ter